# Doubt about the classical way to solve the gaussian integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, gaussian-integral

Probably the most known way to solve
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$$
Is considering
$$I^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy$$
My doubt is really basic and somehow I understand why it makes no sense, but I would like to know more expert opinions. The doubt is why we use another variable, the variable $y$, and not another variable $x$ so we could get the (wrong) integrand $e^{-x^2-x^2}=e^{-2x^2}$.

My thought is that in general in double integrals the variables are referred to two different sets $A$ and $B$ and so, even if $A=B$, we can't sum them because they are distinct objects of two sets; but I know too that integration variable are dummy variables and it is the same to consider $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ or $\int_a^b f(t)dt$ and sum them, even if in that case they are the same number.

Why is this wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You mean $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$, of course.

Comment: One can summarize this problem by writing $$\left(\int f(x)dx\right)^2\ne\int f^2(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you would easily understand this if you compare with sums. Note that $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac  1 {2^{k}}=1$. Hence $( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac  1 {2^{k}})^{2}=1$. But if you write $( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac  1 {2^{k}})^{2}$ as $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac  1 {4^{k}}$ you would end up with $\frac {1/4} {1-1/4}=\frac 1  3$. So $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^{2}=\sum_k a_k \sum_j a_j =\sum_{j,k} a_ja_k$ and not $\sum_k a_k a_k$.

Comment: Or even $(-1+1)^2 \neq (-1)^2 + 1^2$